# 404 Page Not Found codeigniter url

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I am a beginner using codeigniter. I am using following url "http://localhost/ci/index.php/shopcart" to access the controller and I am getting error 404 page not found

### Controller Code

```
     <?php

    class Cart extends CI_Controller { // Our Cart class extends the Controller class

        function Cart()
        {
            parent::CI_Controller(); // We define the the Controller class is the parent. 

        }


    }

        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('cart_model'); // Load our cart model for our entire class 
            $data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products(); // Retrieve an array with all products
            $data['content'] = 'cart/products'; // Select our view file that will display our products
            $this->load->view('index', $data); // Display the page with the above defined content
        }
?>
```

### Model Code

```
<?php 

class Cart_model extends Model { // Our Cart_model class extends the Model class
// Function to retrieve an array with all product information
    function retrieve_products(){
        $query = $this->db->get('products'); // Select the table products
        return $query->result_array(); // Return the results in a array.
    }  

}
```

### Route

```
$route['default_controller'] = "shopcart";
```

### autoload

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('cart' , 'database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('form');
```

Comment: http://localhost/ci/index.php/shopcart is the problem, since it is searching for index.php folder.

Try http://localhost/ci/shopcart

Comment: Your class name seems as Cart, so you can try http://localhost/ci/index.php/cart or http://localhost/ci/cart/

Comment: http://localhost/ci/shopcart displays "The requested URL /ci/shopcart was not found on this server." http://localhost/ci/index.php/cart also displays 404 page not found. I am using codeigniter 3

Comment: This is not good code for CI3. This is code used in CI v <= 1.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

codeigniter works on base_url~/index.php/class_nm/function/segment3. Now in your case change file name `Cart.php`.

[localhost/ci/index.php/cart/index](http://localhost/ci/index.php/cart/index)

and make sure your function `index` is `public`, I guess it will fix your problem :)

Comment: localhost/ci/index.php/cart/index is also showing 404 Page Not Found my index function is public by default as mentioned in the attached code with this question. And Please note that my controller file is shopcart.php

Comment: change it to Cart.php

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the 404 page not found error because controller "shopcart" is not defined. Instead you have defined a controler "cart".  So you should try  `localhost/ci/index.php/cart` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the url helper as well. That works for me!