# Error: 404 Page not found in codeigniter Bonfire logs file on every page load

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

I am new to using codeigniter. I'm using codeigniter bonfire framework for creating application. Every time when i load page, logs file generate an error:

> ERROR - 2015-06-10 05:30:12 --> 404 Page Not Found -->
>   ERROR - 2015-06-10 05:30:18 --> 404 Page Not Found -->

How to solve this error and where to create a 404 page in application?

Here is my routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "restaurant"; 
$route['404_override'] = ''; 
$route['login'] = 'users/login'; 
$route['register'] = 'users/register'; 
$route['logout'] = 'users/logout';
```

Comment: We need to see your code to help you otherwise check this [404 Page Not Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095884/404-page-not-found-codeigniter-url) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752609/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-but-why)

Comment: which file code u want to see.

Comment: check the links in my comments